# customize markdown parse on vuejs

Tags: markdown, markdown-it

i have problem with use libary `markdown-it` it with parse markdown-it. i want when my formatText `\\my_text\\` it can change to italic. based on markdown-it when text want change italic use `*italicized text*`. how can i change the format of the text i mean `\\my_text\\` parse to italic when use library markdown-it or parse another many format text

```js
//my code markdown-it , use mixin vue
const MarkdownIt = require('markdown-it')
const md = new MarkdownIt({
    html: true,
    linkify: true,
    typographer: true
});

export default {
    methods: {
        marked(payload: string): string {
            if (payload) return this.parse(md.render(payload));
            return "";
        },
        parse(payload: string, type: any = "") {
            const parser = new DOMParser();
            const htmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(payload, "text/html");
            const links = htmlDoc.querySelectorAll("a");
            links.forEach(link => {
                link.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
                link.classList.add(
                    "hover:underline",
                    "hover:text-orange",
                    "text-indigo-200"
                );
            });
            if (type === "commentTask") {
                const divs = htmlDoc.querySelectorAll(
                    ".phabricator-remarkup-embed-layout-link"
                );
                divs.forEach(div => {
                    const url = div.attributes.item(0)?.value;
                    div.classList.add("border", "border-red-300", "p-2", "w-72", "mt-2");
                    const spans = div.querySelectorAll(
                        ".phabricator-remarkup-embed-layout-name"
                    );
                    spans.forEach(span => {
                        const newA = htmlDoc.createElement("a");
                        newA.classList.add("hover:text-orange", "mr-1", "pr-1");
                        newA.innerHTML = span.innerHTML;
                        newA.setAttribute("href", url as string);
                        newA.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
                        span.innerHTML = "";
                        span.appendChild(newA);
                    });
                    const as = div.querySelectorAll(
                        ".phabricator-remarkup-embed-layout-download"
                    );
                    as.forEach(a => {
                        a.classList.add("ml-2");
                        a.removeAttribute("target");
                    });
                });
            }
            return htmlDoc.documentElement.innerHTML;
        }
    }
};
```

```html
<!-- my code use vueJS, Vuejs mixins-->
<div
                id="vue-html"
                class="text-sm p-4 overflow-y-auto text-black border-2 mt-3"
                style="max-height: 30rem"
                v-html="marked(data)"
            />
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you replace \\ with *?

```
marked(payload: string): string {
            if (payload) return this.parse(md.render(payload.replace(/\\\\/g, '*')));
            return "";
        }
```

Comment: for a while I thought like that, but at least I need to change 3 or more text formats such as italic, link, numbering and another. if i do as you do , I guess it will be a little troublesome. thank for your suggest @antonio